# Meta box com os recursos de post

Tags: wordpress

Olá!

Fiz um tema para Wordpress com algumas meta boxes no custom post type, porém precisava utilizar uns plugins nessas meta boxes, mas eles só funcionam na box principal ali do post.

Como faço para dar os recursos do post principal para as meta boxes? Existe possibilidade?

Obrigado!

edit:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Isso que preciso, fazer uma galeria do NextGEN funcionar na minha meta box.

Comment: Quais recursos do post principal?

Comment: Poder usar os plugins, poder usar aqueles botões que tem ali em cima, como formatador de texto, essas coisas... No caso queria clonar a box do post mesmo. Várias vezes. Existe possibilidade?

Comment: Pode adicionar um par de screenshots? Assim, verbalmente, não sei exatamente do que está falando...

Comment: Confere também se nos parâmetros do seu CPT não está faltando alguma functionalidade que precisa. Tipo `'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes')` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters

Comment: Testei todos os atributos do 'supports' mas mesmo assim não deu certo... Subi um print ali pra ilustrar melhor.

Comment: Nossa... mega-advanced... quando puder confiro essa técnica, pra mim é novidade

Comment: Caminho das pedras: [Solution to render Shortcodes in Admin Editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/36568/12615) . Mas acho que não é exatamente o que procura, e pelo que entendi do seu screenshot desconfio que não é possível.

Comment: Não é exatamente o que eu quero. No link ele busca um jeito de facilitar os posts do usuário, apenas. De qualquer forma, vou dar uma olhada, talvez eu consiga mudar o meu esquema aqui e integrar mais meta boxes dentro do post, em vez de fazer tudo separado! Obrigado!!

Mas se por acaso alguém descobrir se é possível utilizar os recursos do editar na meta box, por favor, compartilhe aqui com o grupo!

Comment: Editar no metabox é fácil, acho que não está explicando bem o que quer...